# Kotlin AES BAD_DECRYPT

Tags: java, android, kotlin, encryption, aes-gcm

I am trying to encrypt and decrypt strings/files within Kotlin.
I am using the following tutorial which is in Java https://mkyong.com/java/java-aes-encryption-and-decryption/ to make this happen.

When I tried to run it, it throws an error of "... Cipher functions:OPENSSL_internal:BAD_DECRYPT ..." It goes wrong when the doFinal is executed within the Decrypt function.

I'am trying to fix this for hours now, but no luck.

This is the code.

```
   private const val ENCRYPT_ALGO = "AES/GCM/NoPadding"

    private const val TAG_LENGTH_BIT = 128 

    private const val IV_LENGTH_BYTE = 12
    private const val SALT_LENGTH_BYTE = 16
    
    fun getRandomNonce(): ByteArray {
        val nonce = ByteArray(16)
        SecureRandom().nextBytes(nonce)
        return nonce
    }
    
    fun getAESKeyFromPassword(password: CharArray?, salt: ByteArray?): SecretKey {
        val factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256")
        val spec: KeySpec = PBEKeySpec(password, salt, 65536, 256)
        return SecretKeySpec(factory.generateSecret(spec).encoded, "AES")
    }

    
    fun encryptFile(pText: ByteArray, password: String): String {
        
        val salt: ByteArray = getRandomNonce()
        val iv: ByteArray = getRandomNonce()
        
        val aesKeyFromPassword: SecretKey = getAESKeyFromPassword(password.toCharArray(), salt)
        val cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ENCRYPT_ALGO)
        
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesKeyFromPassword, GCMParameterSpec(TAG_LENGTH_BIT, iv))
        val cipherText = cipher.doFinal(pText)
        
        val cipherTextWithIvSalt: ByteArray =
            ByteBuffer.allocate(iv.size + salt.size + cipherText.size)
                .put(iv)
                .put(salt)
                .put(cipherText)
                .array()
        
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipherTextWithIvSalt)
    }


    fun decryptFile(cText: String, password: String): String {
        val decode: ByteArray = Base64.getDecoder().decode(cText.toByteArray())
        
        val bb: ByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(decode)
        val iv = ByteArray(IV_LENGTH_BYTE)
        bb.get(iv)
        val salt = ByteArray(SALT_LENGTH_BYTE)
        bb.get(salt)
        val cipherText = ByteArray(bb.remaining())
        bb.get(cipherText)
        
        val aesKeyFromPassword: SecretKey = getAESKeyFromPassword(password.toCharArray(), salt)
        val cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ENCRYPT_ALGO)
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aesKeyFromPassword, GCMParameterSpec(TAG_LENGTH_BIT, iv))
        val plainText = cipher.doFinal(cipherText)
        return String(plainText, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
    }
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: `decode(cText.toByteArray())`
 should be `decode(cText)`

Comment: @kelalaka I already tried that, which makes sense to decode to ByteArray. But no luck. It givis me same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug is that in `encryptFile()` the salt and IV are determined using the `getRandomNonce()` method, which returns a random 16 bytes array. But in `decryptFile()` it is assumed that the IV has a length of `IV_LENGTH_BYTE` (12 bytes) and the salt has a length of `SALT_LENGTH_BYTE` (16 bytes). I.e. both implementations are inconsistent regarding the IV length. Note that for GCM the IV must indeed have a length of 12 bytes.

A possible fix would be to modify the `getRandomNonce()` method as follows:

```
fun getRandomNonce(size: Int): ByteArray {
    val nonce = ByteArray(size)
    SecureRandom().nextBytes(nonce)
    return nonce
}
```

and the following change in `encryptFile()`:

```
val salt: ByteArray = getRandomNonce(SALT_LENGTH_BYTE)
val iv: ByteArray = getRandomNonce(IV_LENGTH_BYTE)
```

With these changes, the code is successfully executed on my machine.